# Keras Functional API: "Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (X, Y)"

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to fit a ConvNet model using Keras' fit generator, but it fails when trying to feed the data to the input layer. It's telling me it's expecting a  three-dimensional input, but my input is only two. If I add a channel to my input shape, it asks for four dimensions.

Here's the exact error when I don't add a channel parameter:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 597)
```

And again when I change the input shape to (1000, 597, 1):

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1000, 597)
```

Here's the code for my model:

```
def initialise_model():
    input_layer = Input((1, 1000, 597))
    conv_layer_1 = Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(10, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(input_layer)
    conv_layer_2 = Conv2D(filters=30, kernel_size=(8, 1), strides=(8, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_1)
    conv_layer_3 = Conv2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(6, 1), strides=(6, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_2)
    conv_layer_4 = Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_3)
    conv_layer_5 = Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=(5, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding="same", activation="relu")(conv_layer_4)
    flatten_layer = Flatten()(conv_layer_5)
    dense_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(flatten_layer)
    label_layer = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(dense_layer)
    output_layer = Dense(1, activation="linear")(label_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

    adam_optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
    model.compile(optimizer=adam_optimiser, loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy", "mean_squared_error"])
    return model
```

And my fit generator:

```
model = initialise_model()
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0, patience=0, verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)
model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=1, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

It's worth noting that the output of my generator is as expected, with the correct shape.

Many thanks

Comment: what is you target shape?

Comment: please provide full error

Comment: please provide generator code too, why you need a reshape layer??

Comment: @IoannisNasios the target shape of the convnet is (1000, 1)

Comment: @Mukul As someone else pointed out, the reshape was a mistake on my part and it's been removed from the sample code

Comment: what is 597 in Input((1, 1000, 597))?

Comment: @IoannisNasios the number of data points in each sliding window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set our input layer as

```
input_layer = Input((1, 1000, 597))
```

or if channels are set to last

```
input_layer = Input((1000, 597, 1))
```

and make sure that your generator yields x_train data of shape

```
(batch_size, 1, 1000, 597)
```

or

```
(batch_size, 1000, 597, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) for Convolutional layers. The input shape should be `(batch, channels, rows, cols)` for 2D convolutions. That means you need to pass `(channels, rows, cols)` to your `Input`-layer. There is actually no need for an reshape-layer as far as I can tell.

What are the dimensions of your images? I assume you want to pass images since you use 2D convolutions, but it looks a little bit more like you're trying to pass vectors.

Your loss is MSE which is fine, but your metric is accuracy. Why?

Comment: Having changed my code to reflect your suggested changes, I'm still getting the same error. I'll update the code in my question though! 

I'm using the generator to produce sliding windows, which is why I'm using 2D convolutions.

Answer (score 0):

conv2D layer has by default `data_format = "channels_last"` if you want to use image having a shape (1, 1000, 597) then you have to set `data_format = "channels_first"` or change input dim to (1000, 597, 1)